How to count number of occurrences in a row for a given value
I have a Google Sheet named "Calendar" that is formatted like this:




07/12/2024
07/11/2024
07/10/2024
07/09/2024
07/08/2024
07/05/2024
07/04/2024
07/03/2024
07/02/2024
07/01/2024
06/28/2024
06/27/2024
06/26/2024




George Washington
Out - Called Off - Sick
Here
Here
Out - Called Off - Car trouble
Here
Here
Out - No Call/No Show
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here


Ben Franklin
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here


Thomas Jefferson
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Out - Scheduled Off - Vacation
Out - Scheduled Off - Vacation
Out - Scheduled Off - Vacation
Out - Scheduled Off - Vacation
Here


John Adams
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here


Patrick Henry
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Out - Scheduled Off - Doctor appointment
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here


Teddy Roosevelt
Out - Scheduled Off - New baby
Out - Called Off - New baby
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here
Here



Names of employees are in Calendar!A2:A like so:

On a separate tab named "Attendance", in cell A2:A, I have all the names in Calendar!A2:A.  I am trying to figure out how to count how many times the value "Out" appears in the row associated with each employee.  I have tried many different formulas, but I can't get any results.
Here is how it should look on "Attendance" sheet, based on the data in "Calendar" sheet:

With the following formula, I can get the actual results, but not the count: =INDEX(Calendar!$B$2:$N$7, MATCH(A2,Calendar!$A$2:$A$7,0)).  Also, I would prefer to achieve this with an ARRAYFORMULA.


You may try:
=map(A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(Σ,countif(filter(Calendar!B:Z,Calendar!A:A=Σ),"*Out*")))



This turns out to be the best answer.  Thank you.  Very adaptable to my needs.

I've seen you use this syntax a few times recently, but I can't seem to wrap my head around why A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))) works to find the last row with values. Can you provide any feedback that might help explain it?

@Kreeszh certain functions like index, offset, xlookup when used in conjunction with a range operator : (colon) will serve the cell address instead of the value present in that address. It can be used in the forms of  index():index() or index(): or :index()  https://i.sstatic.net/AJLWgOn8.png

You can try adding this formula to B2
=MAP(tocol(A2:A,1),LAMBDA(k,reduce(0,FILTER(Calendar!A:N,Calendar!A:A=k),lambda(a,c,if(isnumber(search("Out",c)),a+1,a+0)))))



Thank you. That works as long as the names in "Attendance" tab are in the same order as the names in the "Calendar" tab.

I apologize, I corrected the formula and it should work agnostic to the order of the Attendance table now.

={Calendar!$A2,COUNT(ARRAYFORMULA(FIND("Off", Calendar!$B2:$N2)))}

That works if I change the formula to ={Calendar!$A2,COUNT(ARRAYFORMULA(FIND("Out", Calendar!$B2:$N2)))} and if I drag the formula down column A, but I couldn't figure out how to expand it into an ARRAYFORMULA.

What's the purpose of the ARRAYFORMULA?

To output all the employees with their days off down the column without having to drag the formula down as the number of employees grows.
